# Azure policies, integration testing

Tags: azure, integration-testing, azure-policy

I'm new to azure and I have some azure policies to implement controls over azure services.

I was wondering if there exist any integration testing frameworks or tooling support to test azure policies?

Can I create mock objects for azure services and test if the policies work as expected or not?

Answer (score 0):

No, there exists none, sadly. You'd need to create your own. You can use various SDK and\or Powershell\CLI